# How to use updateview with a ForeignKey/OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

```
class ModTool(models.Model):
...
issue = models.OneToOneField(Issue)
priority = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PRIORITY, blank=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS, default='O', blank=True)
```

url

```
url(r'^moderate/(?P<pk>\d+)', ModEdit.as_view(),name='moderation')
```

view

```
class Modedit(UpdateView):

    model = ModTool
    template_name = 'myapp/moderate.html'
    fields = ['priority','status']
```

At this point I am not able to figure out how to set this view to edit the particular ModTool instance which has the onetoonefield with Issue given in the pk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `slug_field` and `slug_url_kwarg` attributes for this:

```
url(r'^moderate/(?P<issue_id>\d+)', ModEdit.as_view(),name='moderation')

class Modedit(UpdateView):
    slug_field = 'issue_id'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'issue_id'
    model = ModTool
    template_name = 'myapp/moderate.html'
    fields = ['priority','status']
```

This will do a lookup on `issue_id=<issue_id>` where `issue_id` is the issue's primary key as captured in the url.

I've renamed the keyword argument `pk` to `issue_id` to prevent a name clash with the lookup for the primary key. Otherwise an additional filter would take place that filtered on the `ModTool`'s primary key with the value for the `Issue`'s primary key.

Comment: thanks. how did you figure this out? The docs are the most confusing when it comes to CBVs. Btw, if I add a slug field to my Issue model later, would it still work? Sorry but CBVs are very confusing to me.

Comment: @yayu If you later on add a slug field, you can do a lookup across the relationship like you're used to, i.e. `slug_field = 'issue__slug_field'`. My knowledge of CBVs mostly comes from experience and reading the source code, but recently I've found the site [Classy class-based views](http://ccbv.co.uk/), which is a very helpful resource that gathers all the source code and inline documentation for a specific class onto a single page.