# How to get abstract user first_name and last_name and how to update it

Tags: python, django

```
# models.py

class User(AbstractUser):
   `` id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class Employee(models.Model):
    employee = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     reporting_manager = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reporting_managers',
                                          null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_join = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_exit = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I want here `first_name` and `last_name` from Abstract user and that should be also updatable. Help me out this issue.

```
# views.py

class EmployeeUpdateView(UpdateView):

"""
For updating profile of each employee :update view
"""

model = Employee

fields = ('reporting_manager','date_of_birth','date_of_join','gender','address','photo',\
          'department','employee_code','blood_group','designation','phone_no','personal_email_id','official_email_id',\
          'email_domain','city','allowed_apps')

template_name = "registration/update_employee.html"
```

Comment: Those fields are editable by default

Comment: how should i get in views.py and how should i update it. could you pls tell me

Comment: `UpdateView` uses `ModelForm` by default to build a form for your model.


By default, ModelForms allow you to only modify fields of the model.

If you want to edit fields of a related model, you'll have to create your own custom `ModelForm`, validation and saving because you'll be making changes across 2 tables.

Comment: U want to display `first_name` and `last_name` in form?

Comment: This question is already answered here:[click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367212/how-to-use-updateview-with-a-foreignkey-onetoonefield)

Comment: yaa i am getting first name and last name by {{employee.employee.first_name}} but i want to update that  @hariHaraSudhan

Answer (score 0):

```
views.py i added this
def post(self, request, **kwargs):

    """
    This function here for updating first_name and last_name by getting details from update_employee form \
    and explicitly we are adding first_name and last_name by using reference of particular names from form

    """
    data = request.POST.dict()
    print("Data coming from update of employee data ", data)
    emp_code = data['employee_code']                       
    employee = Employee.objects.get(employee_code=emp_code) 
    emp_user = employee.employee                            
    emp_user.first_name = data['first_name']
    emp_user.last_name = data['last_name']
    emp_user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

> In **html** i created explicitly first name and last name inputs for
>   this i added

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{ employee.employee.first_name }}" ><br>
```